# How to check if array is not null in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this where statement in LINQ:

```
(users != null && users.Contains(x.Appointment.UserId))
```

users is an `int[]`. When i run this code i have an exception:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only
>   entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in
>   this context.

What should i do?

Comment: Don't you need to use the ToList() before attempting the Contains?

Comment: Show your real code or example code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Did you copy users to a local variable?

Comment: This is LINQ-to-SQL or Entity-Framework, right? It looks like it's attempting to translate this Where query to SQL, but the LINQ provider doesn't know how to handle int[] in the DB.

Comment: get the null-guard (`users != null`) out of your EF/LINQ-context ...

Comment: What exactly are you calling `Where` on?

Comment: could you share your complete where clause

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Assuming you are starting with something like this:

```
var filtered = appointments
    .Where(x => users != null && users.Contains(x.Appointment.UserId));
```

As @CarstenKönig suggests, try moving the null check outside of the Where clause:

```
var filtered = users != null ? 
    appointments.Where(x => users.Contains(x.Appointment.UserId)) :
    appointments;
```

That means the null check is handled by C#, and LINQ to Entities doesn't attempt to convert it to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested you could move bool check outside the closure and use resulting bool in your `Where` statement:

```
var usersNotNull = users != null;
var users = users == null ? new string[0] : users;
query.Where(x => usersNotNull && users.Contains(x.Appointment.UserId));
```